# sum not calculating correct no. of units in SQL command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL script(of which the result is displayed under the script). The issue I am having is that I need to add up the quantity on the invoice. The quantity works fine when all the products on the invoice are different. When there is a product that appears twice on the invoice, the result is incorrect. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `DISTINCT` keyword acts on all columns you select.

A new product introduces a difference which makes it no longer distinct. Hence the extra row(s).

Where you had:

```
Order Product Total
1     Toaster  $10
2     Chair    $20
```

And another item is added to order 1:

```
Order Product Total
1     Toaster  $99
1     Balloon  $99 -- Yes that's a $89 balloon!
2     Chair    $20
```

The new row (balloon) is distinct and isn't reduced into the previous row (toaster).

To make is distinct again, don't select the product name:

```
Order Total
1     $99
2     $20
```

Uniqueness kicks in and everyone's happy!

If you can remove the column from the select list that's "different", you should get the results you need.

Comment: thanks for explaining Adrian.  the thing is I want to group the two products so it only shows one.  BUT I want to show that it is two in the units.

Comment: Take a look at `group_concat` - It'll put the products into a list and hence in one row.

Comment: sorry for not clarifying but I'm on SQL 2008 so I don't have that function.  is there an equivalent?

Comment: No worries, I was in MySQL mode!

Comment: So you could try and emulate `group_concat`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server But that's nasty.

Comment: don't think I will go there.